# How to locate where a built-in function is defined?

Tags: matlab, shared-libraries, reverse-engineering, built-in, function-definition

In MATLAB, there are roughly 3 ways to define functions: non-comment-only `.m` files, `.p` files, and compiled code (e.g. DLL, MEX).

Knowing *where* a function is defined could be helpful in several cases, such as when a breaking change was introduced to some function outside our control, and we'd like to try to revert to an old version in the hopes of getting our code working again; or when trying to reverse-engineering some undisclosed algorithm.

The `which` function is usually very good at identifying function definitions and their locations (which works for `.m`, `.p` and MEX), but isn't very useful when it comes to shared library functions, where (at best) it points to a comment-only documentation file:

```
>> which _mcheck
built-in (undocumented)

>> which svd
built-in (D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\toolbox\matlab\matfun\svd)
```

If so, assuming a function found within a shared library is called during the execution of my code, **how can I locate the specific file (DLL) that contains it**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that [`dbstop`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dbstop.html) can be used for this. For example:

```
>> which svd
built-in (D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019a\toolbox\matlab\matfun\svd)

>> dbstop svd
Warning: Entering debug mode is only supported within running MATLAB code files. 
Warning: MATLAB debugger can only stop in MATLAB code files, and "libmwmathlinalg>svd" is not a MATLAB code file.
         Instead, the debugger will stop at the point right before "libmwmathlinalg>svd" is called.
```

From there's it's just a matter of finding a file called `libmwmathlinalg` (with the relevant extension) - which isn't a difficult task if your drive is indexed.

Comment: ha! not sure if this is even intended behavior by Mathworks (disclosing the dll, that is), but nice catch

Comment: @AnderBiguri it's sort-of intended, because next to these DLLs there is usually an XML file with all the exported symbols and some additional information.